# Re-use route parameter on url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I make my application route to mydomainname/username/controller.

I am working on asp.net mvc web application that enables a user to belong to multiple account. ie. In the application every account has its own users, and each user in one account can also be a user in another account. What i need is when a user wants to login, they specify the account they want to be logged to like this: domainname.com/accountname/login.

Am able to do this, but where am having issue is how to persist the accountname route parameter across other routes? I mean making it to be visible on the url. For now am using cookie to store and get the accountname parameter, but i need a way to make it visible on the url in every request (without having to manually route it on links) until the user singout.

Am using asp.net mvc 2

**Edit**: Added my route code

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "index" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "dashboard", new { controller = "account", action = "dashboard" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "contacts", new { controller = "contact", action = "index" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "groups", new { controller = "group", action = "index" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "sms", new { controller = "sms", action = "index" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "users", new { controller = "user", action = "index" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "login", new { controller = "Home", action = "login", accountUrlName = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute("", "{accountUrlName}/login", new { controller = "Home", action = "login" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "register", new { controller = "home", action = "register" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "{accountUrlName}/invitations/{ivkey}", new { controller = "home", action = "invitations" });

        routes.MapRoute("", "{urlName}",
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", urlName = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute("", "{accountUrlName}/{action}",
           new { controller = "account", action = "dashboard", id = "", accountUrlName = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute("", "{accountUrlName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "account", action = "dashboard", id = "", accountUrlName = ""});

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: Could you add a little more information? Are you only interested in the login-action for accountnames, and any other action for usernames or do you want the accountname to show up in the username-routes as well? Maybe adding a few more example-routes would clarify.

Comment: I want the account name to show in the url. in my route I have something like this {accountUrlName}/login", new { controller = "Home", action = "login" }. This seems to work fine for the login page, but none other of my controller. even when I speficied something like this: {accountUrlName}/{action}", new { controller = "account", action = "dashboard", id = "", accountUrlName = UrlParameter.Optional }
{accountUrlName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "account", action = "dashboard", id = "", accountUrlName = ""}. this only works for my home page.

Answer (score 0):

So you effectively have two sets of routes here -

`{AccountName}/{Controller}/{Action}` and `{Username}/{Controller}/{Action}`.

Is this right?

It's possible for you to create these routes, but you'd have to have usernames which do not contain account names, and vice versa.